# SQL flipping and getting rows only if non null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with a problem big time and just can't see how it can be done... so any help appreciated from you SQL gurus!

What I have now is a table like this:

```
Sticker Price   Cash Price      Credit Price    Value
Yes             Yes             NULL            107
NULL            Yes             NULL            115
Yes             Yes             NULL            127
```

And what I need to do is construct a table (flipped) to show :

```
Text            Value   IsDefault
Sticker Price   Sticker 1
Cash Price      Cash    0
```

And do not show Credit Price because all values were NULL in the first table.

Basically I want to only show Sticker if it's not all NULL, Cash if it's not all NULL, etc...

I thought of pivot but just cant work my head round it!!!

Currently I have this to give the top table:

```
SELECT SH1.[Sticker Price], SH1.[Credit Price], SH1.[Cash Price], SH1.[Credit Price], UG.Description as Value,
    CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UG.Description)
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as ISDEFAULT
FROM [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroup] UG
    INNER JOIN [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroupMembership] UGM ON UG.UserGroupId = UGM.UserGroupId
    INNER JOIN [XMPDBHDS].[XMPieHDSSchema60].[Sheet1] SH1 ON CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SH1.[Centre Code]) = UG.Description
WHERE UGM.UserId = 1012
```

I just can't see how I can get the table I want from this with my limited SQL knowledge...

Comment: Please format your SQL code, indent it four spaces. Alternatively select the code and press `ctrl k`.

Comment: It might be helpful if we knew what RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL) you were using. Additionally, it is difficult to see how your second table relates to your first.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have indented the code now. It is MSSQL 2008 I am using. Basically the 2nd table needs to show in the Text column the names of the columns in the first table, but only if that column does not contain all NULLs in the 1st table if that makes sense... e.g. 

    A B C |    Yes Null Yes 

|    Null Null Yes

I'd then need convert the above to:
    Text Value |
    A  'some text' |
    C  'some other text'

Skipping B as it didn't contain any values in the 1st table... the Values are just strings I put in to represent A , B and C to be used in another table. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used pivot with luck:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Text], SUBSTRING([Text], 1, CHARINDEX(' ', [Text])) as Value, 
CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Text])
    WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as ISDEFAULT
FROM
( SELECT SH1.[Sticker Price], SH1.[Credit Price], SH1.[Cash Price], UG.Description
FROM [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroup] UG
    INNER JOIN [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroupMembership] UGM ON UG.UserGroupId = UGM.UserGroupId
    INNER JOIN [XMPDBHDS].[XMPieHDSSchema60].[Sheet1] SH1 ON CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SH1.[Centre Code]) = UG.Description
WHERE UGM.UserId = @UserID) U
       UNPIVOT
   (Details FOR [Text] IN ([Sticker Price], [Credit Price], [Cash Price] )
)AS unpvt group by [Text]
```

Results!!!

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should be performing a `LEFT JOIN` instead like

```
SELECT SH1.[Sticker Price], SH1.[Credit Price], 
SH1.[Cash Price], 
SH1.[Credit Price], 
UG.Description as Value, 
CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UG.Description) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END as ISDEFAULT

FROM [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroup] UG

LEFT JOIN [uStore].[dbo].[ACL_UserGroupMembership] UGM 
ON UG.UserGroupId = UGM.UserGroupId

LEFT JOIN [XMPDBHDS].[XMPieHDSSchema60].[Sheet1] SH1 
ON CONVERT(nvarchar(100), SH1.[Centre Code]) = UG.Description

WHERE UGM.UserId = 1012
AND SH1.[Credit Price] IS NOT NULL
AND UGM.UserGroupId IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul thank you for the suggestion however this still gives me a table in the format: Sticker Price - Credit Price  - Cash Price - Credit Price - Value - IsDefault with no values... I would like to "fliip" the table and show only the price type if all rows are not NULL in the original table if that makes sense